# Describing $GL(2,\mathbb{C})$ with generators and relations.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

My question is : how can I describe $GL(2,\mathbb{C})$ with generators and relations ?

I do not know how to start ?

Thanks for your help in advance,

Comment: You can't, at least not with a countable set of generators, as the group has uncountably many elements.

Comment: I don't know that this will help answer your question, but the group is generated by transvection matrices and scalar matrices.

Comment: @Travis Thanks ! But then how can I write the  lower central series (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_series#Lower_central_series) for $GL(2,\mathbb{C})$ ?

Comment: Taking $G_1 := GL(2, \mathbb{C})$, we have $G_2 := [G_1, G_1]$, but any element of $G_2$ has the form $ABA^{-1}B^{-1}$ and so has determinant $1$, so $G_2 \trianglelefteq SL(2, \mathbb{C})$. Since $GL(2, \mathbb{C})$ is nonabelian, $G_2$ is nontrivial, and so because $SL(2, \mathbb{C})$ is simple, $G_2 = SL(2, \mathbb{C})$. Again $SL(2, \mathbb{C})$ is nonabelian, so by induction $SL(2, \mathbb{C}) = G_2 = G_3 = \cdots$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the fact that linear groups such as $GL_n(F)$ may be uncountable (if the field is), there is a nice presentation of groups such as this ("groups of Lie type") in terms of (possibly uncountably many) generators and relations. You may find it in the legendary notes of Robert Steinberg *Lectures on Chevalley groups*, available online here

[http://math.soimeme.org/~arunram/resources.html](http://math.soimeme.org/%7Earunram/resources.html)

Comment: I think the link should be replaced with: http://www.math.utah.edu/~ptrapa/math-library/steinberg/steinberg-yale-notes.pdf

Comment: @hello Thanks! Instead of replacing the link to Ram's webpage with the link to Trapa's webpage in your comment, I'm fixing the link to Ram's webpage so that both are here (more robust that way). A second benefit is that your link points to scans of the original notes, while the link above in my answer points to a re-typeset version of the same thing (with "expandable proofs"). So people can see both!